# Error in v-on handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading apply)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

as the title said I have an issue that I couldn't figure out why he occurred.
I have a store(using vueX) which configured as followed:

**Index.JS:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import users from "./users";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        users
    }
});
```

And Users.JS (as Suggested to be configured via some online guide I found):

```
import Vue from "vue";
import demoAPI from "@/demoAPI";
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = { user_key: "", list: {} };

const getters = {
    activeUser(state) {
        return state.list[state.user_key];
    }
};

const actions = {
    async getUser({ commit }) {
        demoAPI.getUser().then(user => {
            const { key } = user;
            commit("updateUserList", { key, user });
            commit("setUserKey", key);
        });
    },
    async updateUser({ commit }, data) {
        demoAPI.updateUser(data).then(user => {
            const { key } = user;
            commit("updateUserList", { key, user });
        });
    }
};

const mutations = {
    setUserKey(state, key) {
        state.user_key = key;
    },
    updateUserList(state, { key, user }) {
        Vue.set(state.list, key, user);
    }
};

export default { state, getters, actions, mutations };
```

And also by suggestion I'm using a demo template to pass the parameters:

```
const API_RESPONSE = {
    clientName: "",
    clientBusinessName: "",
    clientSpeciality: "",
    clientEmail: "",
    clientPhone: "",
    clientAddress: "",
    clientFBUrl: "",
    clientInstaurl: "",
    clientProfileIMG: "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/26/3c/40/263c40c3b20771834106fcf0dbde737f.jpg"
};

export default {
    getUser() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return resolve(API_RESPONSE);
        });
    },
    updateUser(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let user = API_RESPONSE;
            Object.assign(user, data);
            return resolve(user);
        });
    }
}
```

**For example, I'll put here a single form input which designated to receive the params and pass them to the store:**

```
<input type="text" class="input" id="clientName" :value="activeUser.clientName"  @input="updateLocalUser($event)"  placeholder="Enter your full name">
```

**And finally, the mapgetters and actions from the form component:**

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["activeUser"])
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['updateUser']),
    updateLocalUser(e) {
      this.$set(this.userToSave, e.target.id, e.target.value);
    },
  },
```

The Error pop in console right after I'm hitting the submit bottom, What can be wrong?

Edit: This error also pop in the console:

> backend.js:2143 TypeError: store.subscribe is not a function

Comment: There is no `store.subscribe` in your example code - please post the actual code, or a link to an example app.

Comment: I know there isn't, I don't know where the hell this error comes from.
I have posted all the code that matters for the more important error I have